# NEARprotocol: Why is AssemblyScript smart contract development only for non financial use cases?

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

In the NEAR protocol smart contract development documentation for AssemblyScript it says:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

big fan of [your work](https://petersalomonsen.com)

the Rust-to-Wasm toolchain is the most mature in the industry and Rust offers safety guarantees that no other language can

AssemblyScript is a young language maintained by a small community of developers so the compiler hasn't had anywhere near as much attention as the Rust compiler has

if someone is building a contract that manages a lot of value, they should be using the best possible technology to solve the problem.  in this case, that's Rust.

AssemblyScript makes it easy for web developers to learn to write smart contracts in a matter of hours.  Rust takes a *little* longer, maybe some weeks of practice sparring with the borrow checker in the dojo ;)

below is a slide from our [Intro to NEAR for Senior Developers](https://hackmd.io/@nearly-learning/near-201)

[image: assemblyscript vs rust]

Comment: thanks for the answer and for nice feedback on my work :)